# React App Builds Successfully but Results Not Printed on Port Opened

Tags: reactjs

I've developed a simple React app using Reach, and I'm encountering an issue when trying to run it locally. After running npm start, the build process completes successfully, and the server is supposed to be serving at http://localhost:3000. However, when I visit this URL, the expected results are not displayed. It's as if the app is not rendering properly or the content is not being served correctly.

Here's the output I receive after running npm start:

build was successful with Serving!

- Local: http://localhost:3000
- Network: http://192.168.100.2:3000

I've double-checked my code, and everything seems to be in order. Has anyone else encountered a similar issue before? Any insights or suggestions on how to debug and resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

here's the code in the app file

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import BloodPressureTable from './components/BloodPressureTable';
import Chart from './components/Chart';
import WHOIndicatorScores from './components/WHOIndicatorScores';

function App() {
  const [bloodPressureData, setBloodPressureData] = useState([]);
  // Function to add a new entry to the data
  const addDataEntry = (newEntry) => {
    setBloodPressureData([...bloodPressureData, newEntry]);
  };


  // State to manage form inputs
  const [newEntry, setNewEntry] = useState({
    time: '',
    date: '',
    amPm: '',
    systolic: '',
    diastolic: '',
    heartRate: '',
    comments: '',
  });

  // Function to handle form submission
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addDataEntry(newEntry);
    // Reset form fields after submission
    setNewEntry({
      time: '',
      date: '',
      amPm: '',
      systolic: '',
      diastolic: '',
      heartRate: '',
      comments: '',
    });
  };

  // Function to handle input changes
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setNewEntry({
      ...newEntry,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Blood Pressure Tracker</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Time:
          <input type="text" name="time" value={newEntry.time} onChange={handleChange} />
        </label>
        {/* Add other input fields for date, amPm, systolic, diastolic, heartRate, comments */}
        {/* Make sure to add appropriate labels and onChange handlers */}
        <button type="submit">Add Entry</button>
      </form>
      <BloodPressureTable data={bloodPressureData} />
      <Chart data={bloodPressureData} />
      <WHOIndicatorScores />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: without code and proper screenshots no one will be able to solve your problem, please update your question with sufficient data.